# How to calculate 'characteristic strength' based on small number of test results?

Tags: statistics

In engineering, we often talk about the 'characteristic strength' of a material, which is the strength that would be exceeded by 95% of test specimens in a population.

The assumption here is that the strength of all the specimens in a population is normally distributed, which is generally accepted.

One common problem that is encountered in real life is trying to determine the characteristic strength based on a relatively small number (*n*) of physical test results. This could be as small as *n* = 2~5 specimens.

My understanding is that it is not quite as simple as taking the mean of these test results and subtracting 1.645 times the sample standard deviations (to get to the 5th percentile). I believe that it should depend on the number of test results and the level of confidence, which is somehow based on Student's t-test according to the following:

*characteristic strength = (sample mean) - (Student's factor) x (sample standard deviation)*

where Student's factor relates to the 5th percentile, with n-1 degrees of freedom and a 50% acceptance probability.

As an example, suppose we have 4 test results of 35.0, 32.2, 36.7, 38.1 MPa (4 samples).

Sample mean = 35.5 MPa

Sample standard deviation = 2.54 MPa

Degrees of freedom = 4 - 1 = 3

t0.95 with DOF of 3 = 2.353

Characteristic strength = 35.5 - 2.353*2.54 = 29.5 MPa

Is this basically correct?

Any insights here would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is quite correct. The $t$ distribution is suitable for tests and/or confidence intervals for the population mean, and is not relevant to the actual target you want: an estimate of the 5% population quantile.

This seems like a **quantile estimation** problem; this [Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample) lists various methods.